# Sitecore Diagnostics Tool shows a lot of warnings for Configuration Pipelines consistency for CD role

Tags: configuration

I'm installing a Content Delivery node, and accordingly, to [Sitecore guidelines](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server) says that some [CONFIG files must be disabled](https://doc.sitecore.net//~/media/0E14F3842E1A411B9811DB17B695B7B2.ashx?la=en).

As I've done it manually, I was expecting that Sitecore Diagnostics Tool would check it, and in fact, it did. However, now I'm seeing a lot of warnings and don't know if would be safe to ignore.

1. Launched Sitecore Diagnostics Tool
2. Choose the Local Sitecore instance
3. Marked on "Selected instance is" these boxes **Content Delivery** and **Production**
4. Marked on "Selected test categories" these boxes **General**, **Security Vulnerabilities**, **Performance and Scalability**, and **Search and Indexing**

> The pipelines/initialize configuration pipeline definition data was changed: 
>   •Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Pipelines.Initialize.Loader, Sitecore.PathAnalyzer
>
> ◦Missing
>
> •Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.CheckWebDAVConfiguration, Sitecore.Kernel
>
> ◦Missing

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: I'm thinking this has to be a bug in the SDT tool. I installed a stock Sitecore 8.2 Update-2 installation and disabled the Sitecore.WebDav.config file and got that issue.

Comment: Seems to as even installing Content Delivery using SIM throws the same error, so it doesn't look like a problem in my manual configuration.

Comment: As an update, I've added an issue in Sitecore Diagnostics Tool GitHub page https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Diagnostics-Tool/issues/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Particularly, I do not think it is a bug. It seems to be just a warning about what was changed in your Sitecore installation.

I have disassembled the SDT code and I have found that this warning is being logged by a class named **PipelinesConsistency.cs** in the assembly **Sitecore.DiagnosticsTool.Tests**.

Basically, the method **Process** compares the "default" Sitecore configuration with what you have and warns you about what is different. Now, that does not necessarily mean that you have something wrong or if it is a bug of the SDT tool. By "default" I mean the initial configuration after installing Sitecore

Here is the path the SDT tool follows to get the default Sitecore configuration:

1. It gets the index.json file according to the Sitecore version you are using from here http://dl.sitecore.net/updater/info/v3/index.json;
2. Next it gets the URL of the showconfig.xml file from the index.json file in the step 1. e. g. http://dl.sitecore.net/updater/info/v3/Sitecore%20CMS/8.2/170614/default/index.json
3. Finally, it gets the default configuration from the showconfig.xml file. e.g. [http://dl.sitecore.net/updater/info/v3/Sitecore CMS/8.2/170614/default/configs/showconfig.xml](http://dl.sitecore.net/updater/info/v3/Sitecore%20CMS/8.2/170614/default/configs/showconfig.xml)

Here is the piece of code that is logging this message:

[image]

Summing up, I believe you will get this message everytime you remove a pipeline/processor that is in the default Sitecore configuration.

Let me know if that makes sense for you.