# Sitecore Diagnostics Tool shows WebDAV must be disabled on CD but it is already

Tags: configuration

I'm installing a Content Delivery (Sitecore 8.2 update 3) node and also running Sitecore Diagnostics Tool to validate it.

In addition to [my other question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6624/sitecore-diagnostics-tool-shows-a-lot-of-warnings-for-configuration-pipelines-co), I'm also seeing a warning that says

> WebDAV must be disabled on Content Delivery server
>
> WebDAV is enabled. It is recommended to disable this feature on CD servers using the WebDAV.Enabled setting

At first, I [followed these steps](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/disable_web_dav_in_sitecore/)

1. Remove WebDAV config references within **log4net**
2. Remove WebDAV config references within **system.WebServer**
3. Remove WebDAV config references within **httpHandlers**
4. Disable Sitecore.WebDAV.config

And after doing them all, the warning remains.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembly that evaluates if the WebDAV is enabled is the Sitecore.DiagnosticsToolset.Tests. I managed to disassemble it and found that it checks the following in the Sitecore configuration to determine whether WebDAV is enabled or not:

```
/configuration/sitecore/settings/setting[@name='WebDAV.Enabled']
/configuration/sitecore/pipelines/initialize/processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.CheckWebDAVConfiguration, Sitecore.Kernel']
/configuration/sitecore/pipelines/preprocessRequest/processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.WebDAVCustomHandler, Sitecore.Kernel']
/configuration/sitecore/pipelines/group[@name='WebDAV']
/configuration/sitecore/webdav
/configuration/sitecore/scheduling/agent[@type='Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupFDAObsoleteMediaData']
/configuration/sitecore/scheduling/agent[@type='Sitecore.Tasks.WebDAVOptionsCleanupAgent']
/configuration/sitecore/mediaLibrary/mediaPrefixes/prefix[@value='$(webDAVPrefix)']
```

[image]

I do agree the warning is not suggestive and maybe the documentation is lacking this information. Please, let me know if that works for you.