# What is Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupFDAObsoleteMediaData in SwitchMasterToWeb.config?

Tags: configuration

I've asked a question about [WebDAV being disabled on Content Delivery servers but Sitecore Diagnostics Tool](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/sitecore-diagnostics-tool-shows-webdav-must-be-disabled-on-cd-but-it-is-already) keeps showing that I was still missing something.

At that time the answer showed what Sitecore Diagnostics Tool uses to verify where WebDAV is enabled or not. So, I ended up finding that `Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupFDAObsoleteMediaData` in `SwitchMasterToWeb.config` was the cause.

That being said I was wondering what exactly `Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupFDAObsoleteMediaData` is used for and the reason of being related to WebDAV if any?

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FDA is short for `File Drop Area` - as in WebDAV File Drop Area.

It's a field type that allows content editors to drag and drop media data (well files) directly into the CMS via WebDAV.

It machine generates folder names to drop these files into; this cleanup task will remove any of these machine generated folders that may no longer be in use.

See also:

- [Sitecore file drop area destination folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422275/sitecore-file-drop-area-destination-folder)
- [File Drop Area - Media save location](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/3468)
- [Sitecore CMS 6.2 - What's New?](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/62/whats_new_62-a4.pdf)

Comment: It makes more sense now! However, the SDT keeps saying WebDAV is enabled until I comment that entire line I added to my question then the 'warning' goes away. Is that the best approach then?

Comment: By enabling "SwitchMasterToWeb", you enable the CleanupFDAObsoleteMediaData task by way of how config patching works. As discovered in your original question, this leads the evaluator to think WebDAV is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

According to the class definition from dotPeek:

> Removes media folders that are no longer referenced via the File Drop Area field.

The File Drop Area field allows you to add fields to templates where you can upload multiple media files without going to the media library. A root folder is specified in config, then when a file is uploaded, a path is created based on a GUID. E.g.

`/sitecore/Media Library/System/C/8/1/5/C815CC829A7979229E47E544FABDC7D6/image.jpg`.

If you then delete the media item, the empty folders will stick around in Sitecore. This processor will find all those folders that no longer have media items in them and remove un-needed ones.